# How to programmatically toggle the console panel from a custom developer tools Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to programmatically toggle the console from inside a custom devtools panel?

What's happening is that on the stock panels, you can press `Esc` to toggle the bottom console panel; but it seems that inside a custom devtools panel, this doesn't work.

The fallback would be to catch the key press and toggle it programmatically but I can't figure out how to do the second part.

I dug through some of the "official" code for devtools and found the `_toggleConsoleButtonClicked` method attached to the `WebInspector` object but I can't find how to access that object from my context.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

For context, I'm working with the [Backbone devtools extension](https://github.com/spect88/backbone-devtools).

PS: there are more keyboard shortcuts that stop working. Things like Ctrl/Cmd+[number] to switch to a different panel, Ctrl/Cmd+R to reload the page. That might mean that it's more of a feature request for Chrome than something I'm missing. In the meantime, if you have ideas for some of these, I'll take them!

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Developer Mode in chrome://extensions/. Here is a nice tutorial to debug Chrome extensions http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear: I'm trying to toggle the console programmatically. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue relative to your question:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=445240

I don't know where is it now...